# Use bootstrap for wordpress gallery?

Tags: gallery, twitter-bootstrap

I am wondering if it is possible to rewrite the gallery shortcode output (default wp gallery) to use bootstrap responsive columns. WP gallery is not really working as the rest of my theme.

I know it must be a way to do it via my theme functions but I need guide.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The gallery shortcode is contained in the `wp-includes/media.php` file.  There is a `function gallery_shortcode(` that does all work.  About 25 lines down you find:

```
    $output = apply_filters( 'post_gallery', '', $attr, $instance );
    if ( $output != '' ) {
      return $output;
    }
```

This code goes out and runs any filters tethered to `post_gallery`, and if there is a result then it does not run it's own code but exits with that filters output.

Okay, with all this known you can now create your own filter like this:

```
    function your_awsome_theme_post_gallery( $output, $attr, $instance ) {
      // your code here
    }

    add_filter( 'post_gallery', 'your_awsome_theme_post_gallery', 10, 3 );
```

Have a look at these two examples:

- Gallery for [Bootstrap 2](https://github.com/vinorodrigues/wp-bootstrap2/blob/master/wp-bootstrap2/inc/gallery.php)
- Gallery for [Bootstrap 4](https://github.com/vinorodrigues/wp-bootstrap4/blob/master/addon/inc/gallery.php)